# How can I detect if the stock music app has been terminated?

Tags: ios, swift, mpmusicplayercontroller

I'm making a music player using `MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer()` to learn Swift and everything is going pretty well except for one small problem; whenever music is playing from my app, and then I switch over to the music app and terminate it via multitasking, the music stops as expected but my app crashes when I switch to it.
I was thinking this might be due to the fact that I have not set a condition for what should happen when music is terminated and I can't seem to find anything in the Apple Docs that actually helps. I tried

```
if (musicPlayer.playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackState.Interrupted) || (musicPlayer.playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackState.Stopped)
```

to no avail. Can anyone offer some insight as to why this is happening and/or a solution?
Here's a sample of my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var notificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()

        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "handlePlayingItemChanged", name: MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification, object: musicPlayer)
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "handlePlayState", name: MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification, object: musicPlayer)

        musicPlayer.beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications()

        if (musicPlayer.playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackState.Playing) {
            playButton.setImage(pause, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            setupCurrentMediaItem()
            handleShuffleAndReplayMode()
            self.isPlay = true
        } else if (musicPlayer.playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackState.Paused) {
            playButton.setImage(play, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            self.isPlay = false
        } else if (musicPlayer.playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackState.Interrupted) || (musicPlayer.playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackState.Stopped) {
            playButton.setImage(play, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            self.isPlay = false
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does using `applicationMusicPlayer` make a difference? `MPMusicPlayerController` is Not Very Good, why not play the music with `AVPlayer`?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not remove the observers you will always throw an exception:

You added observers without condition to remove them:

```
notificationCenter.addObserver...
```

Remove Observers:

```
notificationCenter.removeObserver...
```

Look here for more info -
[Key-Value Observing Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOBasics.html)